# Google image search URL that can be shared?

Tags: sharing, url, google-image-search

I performed a Google Image search, it shows results, but when I send the search URL to someone, they can not see any result:

https://www.google.com/search?as_q=berlin&tbs=sur:fmc&biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=isch#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&ei=VOgBUtS6JcX-lAX6s4CYBA&fp=4119dba43ada9276&q=berlin&sa=X&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbs=sur:fmc,isz:lt,islt:4mp&ved=0CCIQpwU

Actually, the link does not even work in a new tab of the same browser.
Here is how I performed the search:

1. Go to **[search.creativecommons.org](http://search.creativecommons.org/)**
2. Enter ***berlin***
3. Click on ***Google Images***
4. Once you have been redirected to Google Images, click on the ***Size*** filter, select ***Larger than…*** and then ***4 MP (2272×1704)***.

[image: Screenshot of Google Images, searching for berlin, with filters applied]

How to share the resulting link successfully?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem seems to be the part after the #, but it works if you use the **[Google Advanced Image Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search)** directly.

The **full URL** that you will get for the search above:

> https://www.google.com/search?as_st=y&tbm=isch&hl=en&as_q=berlin&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&cr=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,sur:fmc&biw=2560&bih=1342&sei=9QACUs3cPObw4QS-6IEQ

That URL can be **shortened**:

> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=berlin&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,sur:fmc

You can then easily **change the search term**:

> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=vienna&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,sur:fmc

Comment: It seems that the `tbs` argument can also be cut (in fact, this argument gives me different images than if I do a manual google image search): https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=berlin and https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&as_q=vienna

Comment: @HelloGoodbye it could be cut, but then the results wouldn't be filtered according to image size and usage rights, as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 28):

A **basic search** on Google is `/search?q=<query>`

> https://google.com/search?q=space

to make it an **image search**, simply add `&tbm=isch`

> https://google.com/search?q=space&tbm=isch

to add **additional criteria** to your search, use the advanced search tool, and only add the value of `&tbs=<criteria>` from the results.
for example, a >= 4 megapixel teal GIF search would add `&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,ic:specific,isc:teal,ift:gif`

> https://google.com/search?q=space&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:4mp,ic:specific,isc:teal,ift:gif

Note: by `<criteria>` we mean up to an `&`. **Learn more** about URI formatting (including query strings) at...

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples

Comment: Simpler is better.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 2020

Comment: rraallvv all the links in my answer still work. Please explain what you mean by "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: These work as links, but if you paste any of them into the Safari (for Mac) address bar you get a standard web search. Changing q to as_q fixes that.

Answer (score 6):

The secret sauce is `tbm=isch`. [`tbm` stands for "to be matched"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112714/190896), and `isch` is short for "image search."

Example: https://www.google.com/search?q=greyhound+puppies&tbm=isch

Comment: Check [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58550) question for the `tbm` explanation.

Comment: In my question, steps 1 and 4 are the most important, and this answer disregards them.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were asking -- sorry about that. I'm answering the question "what do I need to add to a google search URL query string to make it search images?"

Comment: @Alex: thanks for the pointer about `tbm`. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.google.com/images?q=
```

imagesize:2272x1704 
+ 
near:berlin

```
https://www.google.com/images?q=imagesize:2272x1704+near:berlin
```

https://www.google.com/images?q=imagesize:2272x1704+near:berlin

**explanation :**

hyper text transport protocol

```
http
```

Secured(Encrypted)

```
s
```

network folder

```
//
```

worldwide web

```
www
```

domain name

```
.google
```

domain type

```
.com
```

folder

```
/
```

file

```
images
```

query

 php , a server side program .  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

```
?q=
```

image size

```
imagesize:
```

near

```
near:
```

search word 
search words can not contain spaces . 
use the + , the plus symbol to join each word . 
an example : to+search+for+this+have+to+replace+spaces+with+plus+symbol

can also use location instead of near

```
location:
```

**Example:**

```
https://www.google.com/images?q=imagesize:2272x1704+location:belgium+vegan+restaurant
```

https://www.google.com/images?q=imagesize:2272x1704+location:belgium+vegan+restaurant

If anybody knows what period means, can you please comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the image conditions (size above 4MP and license).

Comment: In my question, steps 1 and 4 are the most important, and this answer disregards them.

Comment: updated the answer .