# What does "tbm" mean in Google Search

Tags: google-search, querystring

What does "tbm" mean in Google Search?
For example: `https://www.google.com/?tbm=dsc`

Comment: On one page in comments some "Johnny" suggested it could mean "Term By Method" , otherwise it's a search result type indicator.

Answer (score 29):

Don't know what it stands for, but the `tbm` URL parameter appears to indicate the filter used. For example:

- Applications: tbm=app
- Blogs: tbm=blg
- Books: tbm=bks
- Discussions: tbm=dsc
- Images: tbm=isch
- News: tbm=nws
- Patents: tbm=pts
- Places:    tbm=plcs
- Recipes: tbm=rcp
- Shopping: tbm=shop
- Video: tbm=vid

So, `tbm=dsc` is "Discussions".

([source](http://stenevang.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/google-search-url-request-parameters/))

However, it also appears that a lot of these filters are also no longer natively available. ([source](http://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-filters-gone-17993.html))

Comment: Even Google's official documentation, uses `tbm` in an example but never defines it, nor lists its valid values! https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#xml-results-for-image-search-queries

Comment: tbm=lcl is used for Local search - this can, for example, be used to find businesses currently open, or open on a particular day of the week, or with a particular minimum rating.  That's actually not for example — those seem to be the only options available in Local Search currently.  Note that it's not actually called Local Search anywhere in the interface.

Answer (score 12):

- `tbm`:  **to be matched**
- `tbm=isch`:  to be matched = image search
- `tbm=isch&q=chicken`: search "chicken" from Google Image Search

you can do the same with `tbs`

- `tbs`:  **to be searched**
- `tbs=imgo`: to be searched = image object
- `tbs=imgo&q=chicken`: search "chicken (image object)" from Google

Comment: Thank you for the info. Could you provide the source of your answer, please?

Comment: tnx but as @AlmirCampos said we need a source for this , for example i readed somewhere that that tbm stands for `"Term By Method"` not "to be matched"!